# What is the CSS (font-family, size) for a blockquote in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would think this was easy to find somewhere, but I haven't been able to. I don't want to use the blockquote class, but create a custom named one. Basically I want the same font and size, but not the border of the blockquote and a custom name.

Could anybody give me the Bootstrap CSS for blockquote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [source code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css) and look for the blockquote tag.

```
blockquote {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    font-size: 17.5px;
    border-left: 5px solid #eee;
}
```

There's lots more.  `CTRL + F` will help you.

Comment: Do you happen to know the font-family?

Comment: I *think* it inherits from the parent element.  Probably `body {  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;  }`